# Existence of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

I was studying [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) and in it, it is useful to have a  transition matrix $M$ that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}M^n$ exist.

So I thought about the existence of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n$ in general($A$ is a square matrix). and it was easy to prove:

> for every diagonalizable matrix $A= QDQ^{-1}$, the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n$ exists **if and only if** elements of $D$ be in the range $(-1,1]$.

but what about **not diagonalizable matrices**? what is the condition for them?

**EXAMPLES:**
$E_1$ is not diagonalizable and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E_1^n$ exists, $E_2$ is not diagonalizable and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E_2^n$ does not exists. 
$$ E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0.1 & 0.1 \\0 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix}, E_2 =  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically do the same thing with the Jordan normal form. You need all eigenvalues to be either in the interior of the unit disk or $1$. Additionally, if $1$ is an eigenvalue, it cannot be defective (defective eigenvalues of $1$ lead to polynomial growth).